# Adapter for small 1/4" ratchet screwdriver to take Leatherman bit tips

Tags: tools

I have a small ratcheting screwdriver as seen [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000XYOUS6), and a Leatherman multi-tool. I have also bought the Leatherman bit accessory pack that contains roughly 40 different bits.

I use both my ratchet and multi-tool a lot, typically for different things. However, on occasion, I noticed some tasks need the Leatherman, because only it has that specific bit. The draw back though, is I lose the ratcheting leverage. So for this type of niche task, I think it would be beneficial to buy an adapter that would allow my small ratchet to accept Leatherman bits. Leatherman bits are flat, rectangular bits, I have included a picture for reference.

[image]

**Question:** What kind of adapter do I need to buy to have my small 1/4" hex bit driver ratchet to accept Leatherman flat bits?

Comment: Looks like it's just a 1/4" hex to square female. Is that all you're asking?

Comment: they look like they are designed to fit a hex socket ( though flattened so only two corners grab). Anyway agree with the answer just get a standard set.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for looking into this! I looked up 1/4" hex to square female and those adapters seem to be intended for actual square bits. The Leatherman bits are totally flat, so I'm not sure if I'd be any better off. Apparently Leatherman bits can be placed inside standard 1/4" hex drivers, but one wonders about the lack of surface area/friction holding it in place. I'm starting to think I might need to create a custom adapter, if I'm dead-set on this.

Comment: that picture you posted is kind of useless. ... instead of showing a picture of all the bits and the holders, show a closeup of one bit viewed from the three sides (top,side,front)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Leatherman bits are standard hex sized only flattened.  They should fit in any standard hex that is open or deep enough for the double sided bits to fit.

However be warned, without the custom sided attachment to grip the long thin side, the reduced surface area is more likely to round off the bits or the tool under significant torque.

[image]

Although Leatherman apparently doesn't think it's a problem as their bit extenders have a standard hex on the end and show it holding these bits.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that you need more leverage, I'd suggest avoiding the Leatherman bits.  As flat as they are, I wonder about how strong they really are, especially since they are meant for a tool without a lot of possible torque.

I'm going to have to suggest getting a regular bit set that likely has all of those bit ends and more.  I use a security bit set found at Harbor Freight that has just about every bit I've ever needed, except for the really tiny ones for ultra small electronics or eye glasses work.

https://www.harborfreight.com/100-pc-security-bit-set-with-case-62657.html

This set also has quite a few of the security bits (that have holes in the end) and other bits for anti-tamper screws.  If nothing else, they are good spares for the regular bits.

Granted, the case is much larger and they aren't as nice to look at, but it's very useful and includes an adapter for 1/4" ratchets.

Doing different Google searches produces results where for an adapter to put regular bits onto a Leatherman screw driver, but not the other way around.